# Precarga de elementos en una LazyVerticalGrid

Tags: kotlin, jetpack-compose

Tengo una LazyVerticalGrid en jetpack compose, la tabla va pegando golpes al deslizar muy rápido hacia abajo en mi dispositivo movil asi que pensé en precargar elementos de margen para que no hubiera ese problema, chatgpt me dijo que podía usar la funcion "prefetchDistance" pero no funciona y no se si es que estoy usándola mal o que no existe (en Google pone que existe, pero no se si existe para el LazyVerticalGrid específicamente). Como se debe usar? Si no existe conocéis alguna alternativa?
Así es como lo tengo usado (no me funciona):

```
LazyVerticalGrid(
        state = state,
        columns = GridCells.Adaptive(screenCells(4)),
        prefetchDistance = 10
    ) {
        items(eDexes) { (comunName, cientificName) ->
            TheButton(comunName, cientificName, navController)
        }
    }
```

Comment: Además de usar ChatGPT, intentaste googlear si existe esa función? Te recomiendo leer [ask] y agregar un [example]

Comment: ya he añadido el codigo y un par de cosas mas que he ido averiguando estos dias